# Converting an array of Pixels to an image in C#

Tags: c#, java, arrays, pixel

I have an array of `int` pixels in my C# program and I want to convert it into an image. The problem is I am converting Java source code for a program into equivalent C# code. In java the line reads which displays the array of int pixels into image:

```
Image output = createImage(new MemoryImageSource(width, height, orig, 0, width));
```

**can someone tell me the C# equivalent?**

Here orig is the array of `int` pixels. I searched the Bitmap class and there is a method called `SetPixel` but the problem is it takes a x,y coordinate number. But what I have in my code is an array of `int` pixels. Another weird thing is my orig array has negative number and they are way far away from 255. In Java this is the same case (meaning both the array in C# and Java have equivalent value) and the values is working fine in Java.

But I can't get that line translated into C#. Please help.

Comment: The negative values are probably because the int values are supposed to be unsigned. It doesn't bother anything if they are signed, but unsigned would make more sense.

Answer (score 6):

Using WPF, you can create a bitmap (image) directly from your array. You can then encode this  image or display it or play with it:

```
int width = 200;
int height = 200;

//
// Here is the pixel format of your data, set it to the proper value for your data
//
PixelFormat pf = PixelFormats.Bgr32;
int rawStride = (width * pf.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

//
// Here is your raw data
//
int[] rawImage = new int[rawStride * height / 4];


//
// Create the BitmapSource
//
BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
    width, height,
    96, 96, pf, null,
    rawImage, rawStride);
```

Comment: I been looking for this and I was goofing with the rawstride value. You code worked like a charm for me.. Thanks... +1 :)

Comment: Where do the 7 and 8 come from in `(width * pf.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/039882h3.aspx) to obtain the bitmap data that you can then manipulate directly, rather than via SetPixel. ([How to use LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229672.aspx))

Comment: +1. If you need to process the whole picture, then SetPixel/GetPixel are SLOW.

Answer (score 2):

I like the WPF option already presented, but here it is using `LockBits` and `Bitmap`:

```
        // get the raw image data
        int width, height;
        int[] data = GetData(out width, out height);

        // create a bitmap and manipulate it
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width,height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        BitmapData bits = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
        unsafe
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                int* row = (int*)((byte*)bits.Scan0 + (y * bits.Stride));
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    row[x] = data[y * width + x];
                }
            }
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
```

With (as test data):

```
    public static int[] GetData(out int width, out int height)
    {
        // diagonal gradient over a rectangle
        width = 127;
        height = 128;
        int[] data =  new int[width * height];
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                int val = x + y;
                data[y * width + x] = 0xFF << 24 | (val << 16) | (val << 8) | val;
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm assuming each int is the composite ARGB value? If there isn't an easy option, then [LockBits](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx) might be worth looking at - it'll be a lot quicker than `SetPixel`, but is more complex. You'll also have to make sure you know how the int is composed (ARGB? RGBA?). I'll try to see if there is a more obvious option...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using LockBits but a slower SetPixel based algorithm might look something like

```
// width - how many int's per row        
// array - array of integers
Bitmap createImage(int width, int[] array)
{            
  int height = array.Length / width;
  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < array.Length; x += width)
    {
      bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(array[i]));
    }
  }
  return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MemoryImageSource](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/MemoryImageSource.html)'s constructor's 3rd argument is an array of ints composed of argb values in that order

The example in that page creates such an array by;

```
pix[index++] = (255 << 24) | (red << 16) | blue;
```

You need to decompose that integer array to a byte array (shift operator would be useful), but it should be in bgr order, for LockBits method to work.

Comment: Your link appears to be dead.