# Unable to pass System.Drawing.Bitmap to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap, interop, hbitmap

I'm writing a DLL in C++ to search a subpicture in a Bitmap.
When the C++ Part is executed, the `HBITMAP` is not valid.

Here is my code:

C#:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("FindSubPicture.dll", EntryPoint = "FindSubPictures", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern System.IntPtr FindSubPicturesFct(System.IntPtr mImg, System.IntPtr sImg, int* nMatches);
    public static System.Collections.Generic.List<TPoint> FindSubPictures(System.Drawing.Bitmap mImg, System.Drawing.Bitmap sImg)
    {
        TPoint* PStack = null;
        int nMatches = 0;
        System.Collections.Generic.List<TPoint> MyList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TPoint>();
        MyList.Clear();

        PStack = (TPoint*)FindSubPicturesFct(mImg.GetHbitmap(), sImg.GetHbitmap(), &nMatches);
        if(PStack == null) { return MyList;}

        for (int i = 0; i < nMatches; i++) { MyList.Add(new TPoint(PStack[i].x[0], PStack[i].x[1])); }
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal((System.IntPtr)PStack);
        }catch(System.Exception ex) { System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        return MyList;
    }
```

C++:

```
#include "FindSubPictures.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct TPoint
{
    int x[2];

    TPoint(int fx, int fy) {
        x[0] = fx;
        x[1] = fy;
    }

    void Reset() { x[0] = 0; x[1] = 0; }
    void Set(int fx, int fy) { x[0] = fx; x[1] = fy; }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) TPoint* FindSubPictures(HBITMAP mImg, HBITMAP sImg, int* nMatches) {
    int mImgWidth = -1, mImgHeight = -1, sImgWidth = -1, sImgHeight = -1;
    TPoint* MyList = nullptr;

    if (mImg == nullptr || sImg == nullptr || nMatches == nullptr) { return nullptr; }


    return MyList;
}
```

Well, the C++ Library function is not doing anything until now. That's because the `HBITMAP` is not valid. In C#, the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is valid.

[image: At a breakpoint]

When I enter "mIng.", no auto-completion is available.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Where are the number of matches in the parameter list?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: My mistake.  The calling function in c# was missing the matches which isn't needed. :  public static System.Collections.Generic.List<TPoint> FindSubPictures(System.Drawing.Bitmap mImg, System.Drawing.Bitmap sImg)

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a bitmap does not mean you can access it like a data field. You'll have to lock the bitmap data in memory first.
See also the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747428/getting-rgb-array-from-image-in-c-sharp) here.

[Bitmap.LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Code would look as follows:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, mImg.Width, mImg.Height);
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
    mImg.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.Read,
    mImg.PixelFormat);

// Get the address of the first line.
IntPtr ptr2mImg = bmpData.Scan0;
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not so sure now why `GetHbitmap()` didn't work. But maybe this gives you an idea. Comment if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the solution.

HBITMAP is only a handle "void *"

You first have to get the complete object by the function `GetObject`

Code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) TPoint* FindSubPictures(HBITMAP mImg, HBITMAP sImg, int* nMatches) {
    int mImgWidth = -1, mImgHeight = -1, sImgWidth = -1, sImgHeight = -1;
    TPoint* MyList = nullptr;

    if (mImg== nullptr || sImg== nullptr || nMatches == nullptr) { return nullptr; }

    BITMAP mBMP, sBMP;
    GetObject(mImg, sizeof(BITMAP), &mBMP);
    GetObject(sImg, sizeof(BITMAP), &sBMP);
    /*Now, BITMAP mBMP and sBMP are valid*/

    return MyList;
}
```